# Only know data type at run time. How to hide data details to other classes which use them

Tags: c++, c++11, runtime, std

Basically I have to populate objects based on an input text file with the following syntax:

```
float 4.55 24 2.1
int 4 6 9 0
float 5.1 6 6
//char 255 3 5
```

And then I need to make some sort of operations on them (for example a simple adition) there is no way to know beforehand which types of data there will be.

I can't store them all internally as double variables because space optimitation is important as well as not loosing precision.

I thought of doing something like:

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual size_t size() = 0;
    virtual void addValue () = 0;
    virtual void getValue (int index) = 0;
};

class BaseFloat : public Base{
public:
    vector<float> data;
    void addValue (float d);
    float getValue (int index);
    size_t size();
}

class BaseInt : public Base{
public:
    vector<int> data;
    void addValue (int d);
    Int getValue (int index);
    size_t size();
}
/* other classes for each data type here*/
```

This doesn't work as each function has diferent return types or parameter needs;

Then I have one class which creates the correct object for each line.

The problem comes when I need to have other class which should work with any type of Base. I was thinking something like:

```
class OtherClass {
public:
    void addValue(Base*, double);
}

OtherClass my_class; //whatever
Base* a = new BaseFloat ();
Base* b = new BaseInt();

my_class.addData(a, 5.56); //Uses BaseFloat::addValue
my_class.addData(b, 6);  //Uses BaseInt::addValue
my_class.addData(b, 6.55); //Uses BaseInt::addValue
```

I was hoping I could do this without adding some sort of long if-else clause
like:

```
void OtherClass::addDataHelper (Base* pointer)
if (subclass(pointer) == float)
    //Do BaseFloat* a = pointer;
    //Do a->addValue
else if ...
```

Any ideas?

Comment: [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) may help solve your problem. Specifically by using [`std::visit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit).

Comment: As your data comes from strings, then your base class should have abstract method `void addValue( const std::string &val )` and each derived class would know how to convert value from string accordingly.

Comment: "Then I have one class which creates the correct object for each line." this class commonly called factory. Read about factory or factory method design pattern.

Comment: C++ is a strongly-typed language. This is a classical, typical issue for strongly-typed languages. You can generalize some things, and make them type-agnostic, in many cases (i.e. templates). But at some point, somewhere, you have to pay the piper and know exactly what type you're dealing with. There is no cookie-cutter answer here. All depends on the particular details. One can cheat, and throw `void *`s everywhere, and defeat C++'s type safety, to get what you want. But, I would go through the expense, and the pain, of implementing a type-safe approach, even if it means more work.

Comment: Without deeper knowledge of what operations you need to apply and how it is difficult to recommend better approach here. There are 2 common ways - OOP as using inheritance that you are trying to implement and metaprogramming using `std::variant` or `boost::variant`. Each has it's own pluses and minuses, your approach of cascade `if` is definetly not the best one (but pretty common for novice programmers)

Comment: If you have c++17 use [std::variant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant). Otherwise if you have boost use [boost::variant](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/variant.html). Otherwise storing them all as doubles is not so bad for storage since if you use polymorphism you'll be hit by the extra pointer/reference anyway.

Comment: @Slava the creation of the objects isn't really a problem it comes when trying to generalice the use of any type of instance on other classes/functions.

Comment: I am not saying it is a problem, I just mentioned that such approach is common, this design pattern called "factory" and you should know about it - then you can learn of common approaches, possible use of existing libraries etc.

Answer (score 1):

When you create OO design you need to define interface of a base class, so all derived classes can override virtual functions **without changing signature**. For example for reading data it can be implemented as this:

```
class BaseData {
public:
    virtual bool addValue( std::istream &in ) = 0;
};

class DataFloat : public BaseData {
    virtual bool addValue( std::istream &in ) override
    {
         float v = 0;
         if( not in >> v ) return false;
         data_.push_back( v );
         return true;
    }
private:
    std::vector<float> data_;
};

class Factory {
public:
    std::unique_ptr<BaseData> create( const std::string &type );
};

std::vector<std::unique_ptr<BaseData>> parsing( std::istream &in, Factory &f )
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<BaseData>> v;
    std::string str;
    while( std::getline( in, str ) ) {
        std::istringstream line( str );
        std::string type;
        if( not in >> type ) continue;
        auto pbase = f.create( type );
        while( pbase->addValue( in ) );
        v.push_back( std::move( pbase ) );
    }
    return v;
}
```

of course this is not complete code, but should be enough to show the idea. So for your operations you need to do the same - find the way to define virtual function in base class, so it can be reimplemented in each derived one without changing signature. Your approach with each class having `void addValue( int data )` or `void addValue( float data )` is not proper OO design and will lead to cascade `if` with `dynamic_cast` or similar approach.

Another solution is to have data in `std::vector<std::variant<int,float,char,double>>` (all necessary types listed) and write proper visitors to do data insertion and calculation etc. There is a lot of materials on internet on how to properly do that and would be out of scope of this answer to add them here.